# Winforms Which Design Pattern / Agile Methodology to choose

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, domain-driven-design, scrum

I have developed desktop (winforms) applications without following any proper design pattern or agile methodologies. Now I have been given the task to re-write an existing ERP application in C# (Winforms). I have been reading about Domain Driven Design, scrum, extreme programming, layered architecture etc. Its quite confusing and really hard (because of time limitations) to go and try each and every method and then deciding which way to go. Its very hard for me to understand the bigger picture and see which pattern and agile methodology to follow.
To be more specific about what I want to know is that:

1. Is it possible to follow Domain Driven Design and still be agile.
2. Should I choose Extreme programming or scrum in this specific scenario
3. Where does MVP and MVVM fits, which one would be a better option for me

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: This is far too general - what does your code do, what are the gereral principles you application has to obide by etc.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to say that its even hard for me to ask myself specific questions about the architecture and design. Since you people are experts, at least you can help me with that. At least you can teach me what would be the right questions I should be asking at this stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a very subjective and debatable kind of topic especially in the developer community. I am just writing down my thoughts. You may derive out the goodness [if any] out of it -

Nobody applies a Design Pattern conciously while designing. There's always an iterative way to reach a good design. The OO principles should be [S.O.L.I.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) You should choose your abstractions cleverly. Try to think in terms of interfaces.

For your legacy code, I think you should first start with the [domain classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model). Basically, where your actual data model resides. Where you talk to your repository / data base. Start refactoring them one by one and create unit tests around them. I am not stressing on Test-Driven here. But, `you need to have solid Unit Tests` because you are rewriting it now. Once your domain classes are ready, it easy to hook on the UI following any standard pattern.

You can have a look at this simple Winforms applications which has all elements of a normal UI pattern alongwith multithreading concept using backgroundworker -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88390/MVP-VM-Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel-with-Data-Bi

This is also very helpful with a code sample detailed explanation - where he shows how to use MVVM for Winforms [parent of the above code project article] -

http://aviadezra.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/mvp-mvvm-winforms-data-binding.html

I can't be more elaborative here as I said its a very subjective topic. You may search on some of [Martin Fowler's](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/appfacades.pdf) articles as you proceed with your design. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail reply. I will go through the articles and try to ask more specific questions next time. Actually I did read about topics like TDD, DDD etc but was unable to understand how all these patterns/concepts relate to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is quite general... I understand you are at the beginning of a big journey.

To help you, I would give you some tips from my experience...

In general, MVVM suits well to medium-big real world applications (even for winforms), so you might start investigating from here. Then you might want to have at least a 3-tier architecture (data-business-presentation). You could also consider the service layer as well, later on the way...

Well... try yourself to stick to something which you understand best now, then get adapted on the way!

As "Angshuman Agarwal" said... try to think in interfaces at every step, this is key to succes.

Good luck!